# How to identify which youtube video is playing now?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

On a page with several embeded youtube videos,

I'd like to perform something based on which youtube video is playing now.

Any ideas on detecting current video info? such as embed youtube url.

So I'm trying to:

- get embed url of current playing video
- Perform some action based on the url.

Comment: By "currently playing video" do you mean to include videos embedded on other pages, incl. pages which may include multiple embedded videos? I'm not sure if there's any way to discern this programmatically...

Comment: I meant how to detect which video a user click to watch on a page with several embedded videos.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the API for retrieving video information here
https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Retrieving_video_information

To get the youtube url use either `player.getVideoUrl()` or `player.getVideoEmbedCode()`

Comment: I don't think this is applicable on a chrome extension.

Answer (score -1):

mm i think you can do this with Javascript Window.event and PHP for data saving i will try write little code and after show you that code .

Comment: This is a chrome extension, you can't use PHP there - only JavaScript.